# Gitlab email configuration issue

Tags: ruby, git, smtp, debian, gitlab

I'm using Gitlab 7.1 CE on debian.

I set up smtp in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

```
unicorn['port'] = 8081
external_url 'http://server_hostname.com:8081'
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.smtp_host.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab@smtp_host.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "secret"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "smtp_host.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = false
```

I'm getting error

> WARN: 553 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user gitlab@smtp_host.com

I don't know why sender email is set to `gitlab@server_hostname.com` instead of `gitlab@smtp_host.com` and no idea how to change it.

Comment: Did you try setting the [email_from](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab/templates/default/gitlab.yml.erb#L29) field?

In `gitlab.rb` try to set it as `gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from']: "gitlab@smtp_host.com"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From email can be set in `gitlab.rb`:

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = "gitlab@smtp_host.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Exim? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#1-packages-dependencies Note: In order to receive mail notifications, make sure to install a mail server. By default, Debian is shipped with exim4 whereas Ubuntu does not ship with one. The recommended mail server is postfix and you can install it with:

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Installing postfix didn't change anything :/

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I don't have any immediate suggestions.